# Curses snake game not removing cells in linux os

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, curses

It's code from a curses tutorial that I've been using to get a grasp of it but even though I've checked the code multiple times, it's still not removing the old cells. The guy that wrote the code is on a mac and I'm using linux so would that be a problem?

```
import curses
import time
import random

screen = curses.initscr()
dims = screen.getmaxyx()
def game():
    screen.nodelay(1)
    head = [1, 1]
    body = [head[:]]*5
    screen.border()
    direction = 0 # 0:right, 1:down, 2:left, 3:up
    gameover = False

    while not gameover:
        deadcell = body[-1][:]
        if deadcell not in body:
            screen.addch(deadcell[0], deadcell[1], ' ')
        screen.addch(head[0], head[1], 'X')
        if direction == 0:
            head[1] += 1
        elif direction == 2:
            head[1] -= 1
        elif direction == 1:
            head[0] += 1
        elif direction == 3:
            head[0] -= 1

        deadcell = body[-1][:]
        for z in range(len(body)-1, 0, -1):
            body[z] = body[z-1][:]

        body[0] = head[:]

        if screen.inch(head[0], head[1]) != ord(' '):
            gameover = True

        screen.move(dims[0]-1, dims[1]-1)
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

game()
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: `body = [head[:]]*5` looks suspicious to me. What happens if you do `body = [head[:] for _ in range(5)]` instead?

Comment: The same thing. The character just prints across the screen and ends when it touches the border. It may have to be something with deadcell. I'm not sure. The code is exactly the same as his.

Comment: Where is this tutorial located?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the guy's code actually worked? Did he run it in the video?

Comment: Yeah, he runs it. His works. The snake is about 5 cells long. edit: oops, sorry. found the video. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9lhsc0igR0)

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is an interesting problem. If only I had a linux box to try it on.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "head[0] -= 1" under the direction==3 conditional case?

Comment: Fixed. Doesn't fix the problem though so I just edited it in. Thanks!lol

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not sure about the lines "deadcell = body[-1][:]" followed by "if deadcell not in body" near the start of the loop -- it seems like deadcell would always be in body, and therefore no cells would ever get cleared. Try moving that initial "deadcell = body[-1][:]" line right above the while loop.

Comment: That worked! Want to provide an answer?

Comment: @acollection_ Done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be near the lines:

```
while not gameover:
    deadcell = body[-1][:]
    if deadcell not in body:
        screen.addch(deadcell[0], deadcell[1], ' ')
```

`deadcell` is always going to be in `body`, so no cells will ever get cleared.

Try this instead:

```
deadcell = body[-1][:]

while not gameover:
    if deadcell not in body:
        screen.addch(deadcell[0], deadcell[1], ' ')
```